# How to frame a simple Factorio/Dyson Sphere factory problem in linear programming using `scipy.optimize`

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to frame a Linear Programming problem from the game Dyson Sphere (a Factorio clone) and then use `scipy` to optimize for it. The problem is as follows:

The problem is as follows: I have a copper mine which produces 150 copper per minute. I can build multiple copper plate factories each of which consume 60 copper per minute and produce 60 copper plates per minute. I want to determine how many factories I should build to maximize copper plate production.

After beginning the process of wrapping my head around the math I'm struggling to get a simplified example to work. I have the following:

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog

c = [-60]
A = [[-60]]
b = [150]
copper_plate_bounds = (0, None)

res = linprog(c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, bounds=[copper_plate_bounds], method='highs')

print(res)
```

The code above will report `message: The problem is unbounded. (HiGHS Status 10: model_status is Unbounded; primal_status is At upper bound)` but I'm not too sure why. Obviously this is a silly matrix but you have `Ax=b` where here it is `-60x=150`. `c` should be negative here as I understand it because I'm trying to maximize the production of copper plates which I do by subtracting from the copper output (150).

Full output:

```
C:\Users\grant\Documents\code\math\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\grant\Documents\code\math\calcular_cobre.py 
       message: The problem is unbounded. (HiGHS Status 10: model_status is Unbounded; primal_status is At upper bound)
       success: False
        status: 3
           fun: None
             x: None
           nit: 0
         lower:  residual: None
                marginals: None
         upper:  residual: None
                marginals: None
         eqlin:  residual: None
                marginals: None
       ineqlin:  residual: None
                marginals: None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Since I'm new I'm not sure if I've misunderstood something mathematically or if I've improperly constructed the constraints of my program.

Comment: You're basically trying to solve min -60*x subject to -60x <= 150, x >= 0, which is unbounded. Note that your constraint is an inequality constraint, i.e. -60x <= 150 instead of -60x == 150 as you're passing `A` and `b` to linprog's A_ub and b_ub arguments instead of `A_eq` and `b_eq`.

Comment: Ah - that's what I was missing. Thanks for spelling that out. I flipped the A to 60 instead of -60 and it worked. Bah, so close. I'm going to expand out the example for some more of the pipeline to make it a bit more robust and then I'll formulate an answer so that this is hopefully more helpful to others who find it